# Converter apps rejecting MS Access 2010 accdb file

Tags: mysql, ms-access, converters, ms-access-2010

I have the [Bullzip MS2mySQL](http://zip.com/products/a2m/info.php) converter and another converter by [Convert-In.com](http://www.convert-in.com/acc2sql.htm) installed.  I am working with a MS Access 2010 accdb file which is working fine in Access but gives errors in both converters.  Both converters work fine when used with an old Access 2007 mdb file.

The Bullzip converter error is "Error 3706: Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed."  I have an [open forum topic over there](http://bullzip.com/phpBB/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=11564) but I have open topics there which are months old with no replies at all.

The Convert-In converter's error is "Unrecognized database format".  Their docs specify Access 2010 support while Bullzip does not make mention of versions supported.

The Access Save As dialogue is not offering me any options other than 2010 accdb.

Does anyone have any advice on this?  Client needs to continue using Access as GUI but I need to fluidly port data to mySQL for our web apps.

// EDIT
My copy of Access 2010 only offers accdb even for new files. So I tried creating a new database in accdb format with 2007 as the version and imported only the tables from the problem file. No forms or queries etc. Same errors from all converters tried.

// EDIT 2
Per HansUp's suggestion to import data into another file - I changed version to Access 2003 and mdb shows up as format and file is opened by converters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*The Access Save As dialogue is not offering me any options other than 2010 accdb.*"

Sorry, I don't have Access 2010 so don't know why it won't let you save as MDB.  However, since that option is unavailable, create a new MDB, then open it and import everything you want from the old ACCDB into the new MDB.  Sounds like you would then be able to use your converter utilities with the MDB.

If at all possible, I would prefer to replace the native Access tables with ODBC links to their MySQL counterparts.  With all the data in MySQL, you could avoid the challenge of synchronizing  data between Access and MySQL.

Comment: My copy of Access 2010 only offers accdb even for new files.  So I tried creating a new database in accdb format with 2007 as the version  and imported only the tables.  No forms or queries etc.  Same errors from all converters tried.

Comment: Changed version to Access 2003 and mdb shows up as format and file is opened by converters!  Thank you!